# Null being added to every element in list list

Tags: list-manipulation

I recently just started using mathematica, and I'm having some trouble figuring out what's wrong with this. When I run this, the output I get adds Null with every element. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. This program is meant to reverse a string without using StringReverse

```
butterfly[word_] :=
     Module[{wordchar = {}}, 
      For[i = StringLength[word], i > 0, i--, 
        AppendTo[wordchar, StringPart[word, i]
         ]
        ]
       wordchar
      ]
butterfly["abcdef"]
```

output: {"f" Null, "e" Null, "d" Null, "c" Null, "b" Null, "a" Null}

Comment: How about: Table[StringPart[word, StringLength[word] - i + 1], {i, 
  StringLength[word]}]

Comment: `StringTake[word, {-1, 1, -1}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE! So, essentially the problem here is that line breaks don't count for anything inside expressions—only *between* expressions. So,

```
a = 4
b = 5
```

is fine, and is interpreted as two separate inputs;

```
a = (Echo[3]
5)
```

is not interpreted as "do `Echo`, then `5`". Within an expression, you need to use `;` to separate sequentially-evaluated parts. Otherwise, line breaks, like spaces, are interpreted as `Times`!

That's relevant here because in the lines

```
For[i = StringLength[word], i > 0, i--, 
        AppendTo[wordchar, StringPart[word, i]
         ]
        ]
       wordchar
```

you're essentially multiplying the output of the `For` loop, which is `Null`, by the list `wordchar`. Since multiplication is threaded over lists automatically, you get `Null` multiplying every string in the list. Check out `butterfly["abcdef"] // FullForm` to see the `Times` explicitly!

So, modifying it to

```
butterfly[word_] :=
     Module[{wordchar = {}}, 
      For[i = StringLength[word], i > 0, i--, 
        AppendTo[wordchar, StringPart[word, i]
         ]
        ];
       wordchar
      ]
```

should fix it!

Note, however, that `For` loops are very "non-Mathematica-l"! Generally, you'll want to use `Table` (or maybe `Array`, or `Sow` and `Reap` for "`AppendTo`—like functionality") to build lists, not `For` and `AppendTo`—and it'll typically be easier than setting up a `For`-loop, since the iterated-over variable already behaves the way you want.

Your code also sets the global variable `i`; "good practice" would be to put it in the `Module` as well (if you were going to use it)!

Comment: Also note `f[word_]:=Characters@StringReverse@word`. (+1)

Comment: @Edmund definitely! OP mentioned they were trying to do it without `StringReverse` though—but similarly, one can technically use `f[word_] := Reverse@Characters[word]`, though this also might be out of the spirit of the exercise I presume OP is doing to gain familiarity with Mathematica 

Comment: Thank you! I know java and python, so definitely more familiar with loops. This was helpful, I'm trying to get more familiar with Mathematica.